# Efficient distributed algorithm for Singular Value decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Is there any distributed algorithm possible for calculating Singular value decomposition of a matrix?
As far as if have explored at many places (like [here](https://www.irisa.fr/sage/bernard/publis/SVD-Chapter06.pdf) pg-132) it is written that because of high communication cost the distributed algorithm is not efficient for Singular value decomposition.
If anyone has some idea about it. Please share some relevant research paper or articles regarding the same.